# How to I copy a variable number of lines from one file to another using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file (WiFi developers might be familiar with it). I want to copy a variable number of lines at the beginning of it to another file. Every wpa_supplicant has the following format:

```
ctrl_interface=wlan0
update_config=1
device_type=0-00000000-0

network={
..
```

After the first few lines the `network={..` part starts however the number of lines above it are variable. I don't know how many lines might be there beforehand. Is there any way to copy all the part before `network{..` to another file using shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic use case for `awk`:

```
awk '{ if ($0 ~ /network=\{/) { exit } print }' wpa_supplicant.conf > /some/file
```

Copying itself is trivial and done via a simple redirection `>`. **Note** that this will overwrite `/some/file`. If you want to append to a file instead of overwriting it, just use `>>`.

More interesting is the first part, which consists of an `awk` script that reads and prints `wpa_supplicant.conf` line by line and stops as soon as a line matches the regular expression `network=\{`.
I'm not going to explain how this script works in detail - if you're not familiar with `awk`, you should read up on it, as it comes in handy quite often when you have to do these kinds of things under time constraints.